# In Adobe InDesign, how can I make edges appear crisp and clean when displaying an exported PNG on the web?

Tags: image, png, adobe, resolution, adobe-indesign

A banner image I create in Adobe InDesign looks great after I export it as a PNG. However, when I upload it to a website all edges lose their crispness and begin to look blurry and generally low quality.

Image export settings are as follows:

[image: Image export settings]

This is the exported PNG, which has crisp text edges:

[image: Exported PNG]

This is how it looks on the web, which is not crisp and doesn't appear to have the same quality.

[image: How it looks on the web]

[image: How it looks on the web close up]

Is there anything in my export settings (or anything else) I should adjust to remedy this?

Comment: I see no problem and no way to improve something in the InDesign settings. And by the way are you using masOS and Retina Display? It can get you a quite blurry image (there are ways to fix it, but has to do with CSS features etc, basically you have to provide two images: with normal size for non-retina displays and with double-size for retina displays and a browser or server shows the proper one)

Comment: Another reason of the low crispness could be if the browser tries to scale up the image. On your screenshots: the first original image looks a little smaller than the second one. It it was scaled by browser it can be the cause.